Using Windows ODBC Driver from C++ program in Cygwin: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
with odbcad32 GUI under Windows i can make a positive test connection to my database.


So now, i want to do the same in C++/Cygwin
      SQLHENV m_henv; 
      HDBC m_hdbc; 



     auto ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &m_henv);
     if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          traceLog("Erreur d'allocation de l'environnement\n");
          return false;
     }
     traceLog("Allocation environnement -> ok\n");

     // Définir la version ODBC
     SQLSetEnvAttr(m_henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

     m_state++; // 1

     // Allouer une connexion
     ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_henv, &m_hdbc);
     if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          traceLog("Erreur d'allocation de la connexion\n");
          return false;
     }
     traceLog("Allocation connexion -> ok\n");

     m_state++; // 2

     // Connecter à la source de données
     ret = SQLConnect(m_hdbc, (SQLCHAR*)"TOTAL", SQL_NTS,
                              (SQLCHAR*)"OSIRIS", SQL_NTS,
                              (SQLCHAR*)"R****1", SQL_NTS);

     if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
          traceLog("Erreur de connexion à la base de données\n");
          return false;
     }

with
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3 -m64 -std=c++11
LDFLAGS=-lodbc32 -static
Compilation is ok but SQLConnect() return an error.
In odbcad32 i can find this:
ipdb            5578-3734   ENTER SQLConnectW 
        HDBC                0x0000000000F47A30
        WCHAR *             0x0000000000F46520 [      -3] "TOTAL\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x00007FFEB1C260E0 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x00007FFEB1C260E0 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 

ipdb            5578-3734   EXIT  SQLConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HDBC                0x0000000000F47A30
        WCHAR *             0x0000000000F46520 [      -3] "TOTAL\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x00007FFEB1C260E0 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x00007FFEB1C260E0 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 

        DIAG [08004] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
 (12154) 

Thank you

Maybe it is not able to find the database, table or user?

Ensure that the connection string for the database is correct. I do not see you set it in your code but make sure you are using Service Name (as per the GUI) and not SID.
